# Is there a male equivalent of "Karen"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, slang

#### Is there a male equivalent of "Karen"?

I have heard a few (e.g., Frank, Bob, Ken), but they don't seem to have the wide currency that "Karen" does. Perhaps they do and I am not aware of it.

Definition of ["Karen"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karen_(slang)) from Wikipedia (emphasis mine):

> **Karen** is a term for a person perceived to be **entitled or demanding** beyond the scope of what is considered appropriate or necessary. A common stereotype is that of a **racist white woman** who uses her privilege to get her own way at the expense of others. Depictions also include demanding to "speak to the manager", being anti vaxxer, or having a particular **bob cut hairstyle**. As of 2020 the pejorative was increasingly being used as a general-purpose term of disapproval for middle-aged upper-middle-class white women.
>
> ... a **Karen's** defining characteristics are **"entitlement, selfishness, a desire to complain"** ... a **Karen** "demands the world exist according to her standards with little regard for others, and she is willing to risk or demean others to achieve her ends."

#### Question:

Is there a male equivalent of "Karen"? If there isn't one, then what word or phrase can be used to reflect most of the qualities mentioned above?

In addition to the qualities, I would also like the word/phrase to have some sense of a distinct appearance (like Karen's bob cut hairstyle) and the racial aspect (but this isn't a must for now).

Comment: I guess it's Ken.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't think this is exclusive to the US. It seems applicable to all woman who share those qualities, including the appearance, age, and the racial aspect.

Comment: Mitch McConnell? Sean Hannity? I would guess that if you used *Hannity*, *Donald*, *Mitch* or *Donald Junior* in the way you would with *Karen* the majority of American English speakers would get it. Oh by the way, thanks for posting the question. I never knew *Karen* had become a slur, but be aware it wouldn't work in the UK. I think that is the point @MichaelHarvey  was making.

Comment: It seems, from [a feature](https://metro.co.uk/2020/04/08/not-karens-meet-women-called-karen-dont-fit-stereotype-12522634/) in the UK _Metro_ newspaper (a free one) that maybe it is now current in the UK.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Aaah, so it's been adopted by the Brits (well some),  social media and Facebook have a lot to answer to.

Comment: We already had Sharons (since the 1980s) who are, roughly speaking, a nationwide version of [Essex girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essex_girl). Like 'Karen', it is a pejorative term, a kind of dismissive generalisation, and not terribly helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some male names floating around out there as purported synonyms to Karen, but in my opinion none are quite synonymous with or well-known as “Karen”. (See for example [Brad](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Brad); a negative male name but lacking all the nuances that “Karen” has, such as the need to see a manager.) Therefore, I would suggest you look no further than “Karen” itself.

“Karen” by itself is sometimes used gender neutrally. For example:

> [Lucius Malfoy was a Karen](https://www.reddit.com/r/harrypotter/comments/g7juu8/lucius_malfoy_was_a_karen/)

Other times they’re called [“man-Karen”](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Man-Karen&amp=true) or “male Karen”:

> Man-Karen wasn't happy about that so he threatened to sue. —[Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/cpmpgj/managers_of_reddit_what_are_your_karen_stories/)

> The male Karen's have really come out of the woodwork —[Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/nekocase/status/1270805914312937474)